# Good reference for abelian category in Weibel's homological algebra

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, homological-algebra, self-learning, abelian-categories

I want to learn some homological algebra from Weibel's book. After reading section 1.1 and 1.2, I find I lack knowledge of abelian category. In section 1.2, Weibel says the constructions on modules in section 1.1 can be applied to arbitrary Abelian category. However, I can't see how to form a quotient (like quotient module) and what the homology is in an abelian category.

I currently have some knowledge in Category theory (Using Emily Riehl's "Category theory in context"), such as limit, adjoint, and monad. But I don't have knowledge of Abelian category. Both Weibel's appendix and CWM treat Abelian category too sketchy, especially on the definition of homology.

I'd prefer that you recommend books or notes that have a complete introduction to Abelian category.

---

Edit: Thank you very much for the books recommended! I think I have found a note that can meet my needs: The first several sections of homological algebra (chapter 12) in [The Stacks project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/browse) seems to be a concise and enough introduction to abelian categories used in homological algebra.

Comment: Riehl uses Freyd's [Abelian Categries](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/freydab.pdf) as a reference, so it might worth having a look.

Comment: "Categories and Sheaves" by Schapira and Kashiwara.

Comment: @Javi @ asdq Thank you!  I have checked the two books. I think Schapira and Kashiwara is somewhat too advanced for me.  And I have not found the explicit definition of homology (Maybe it is my negligence) in Freyd's book. I will try to learn basic theory of abelian category from Freyd's book and check the definition of homology in Schapira and Kashiwara's book.

Comment: I second asdq's suggestion. This is really a marvelous book.

Comment: @QuantumSpace Thanks! I glanced over the book.  The book seems much more sophisticated than Emily Riehl's book. I'll try to read it!

Comment: Z.H. He You don't need everything in it. If I remember correctly, abelian categories start pretty far in the book, but you can immediately start reading it.

Comment: @QuantumSpace OK!

Comment: The homology of a chain complex has the same definition in an Abelian category as in the category of $R$-modules: it's the kernel of $d_i$ modulo the image of $d_{i+1}.$ Thus it's plausible not to find the definition highlighted very specifically, since it's clear what it has to be once you understand what kernels and images are in Abelian categories.

Comment: I would reccomend Borceux' "Handbook of Categorical Algebra" volume 2. It starts fairly basic I think it is very good for an introduction into abelian categories.

Comment: Setion 1.6 of [The Rising Sea](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf) should get you going.

Comment: @Kevin Arlin Thank you! I'll think about it.